# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, header

Here I am trying to read a simple text file and put the content on my page. It's a very simply app but I am still having issues. Below is my code and I have also attached my github repo below.

https://github.com/shanemmay/ExpressJsProblem

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req,res) => 
{
    //trying to write some basic content to the page   
    fs.readFile('test.txt', (err, data) =>
    {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.send("<h1>test complete</h1>");
        res.write(data);

    });
});

app.post("/post", (req,res) =>
{
    //res.send("post");
});

app.listen(8080, () => console.log("App launched"));
```

Comment: This error occurs when you are sending back response more than once for a given request. Here you are sending it twice, first using `res.send` and then `res.write`.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this block in your get function:

```
fs.readFile('test.txt', (err, data) =>
{
    res.set({
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.status(200).send("<h1>test complete</h1>" + data);
});
```

That should duplicate the behavior you're looking for. The above will help you set headers if you need to, and explicitly set the status message, although, all you **really** need is this to do what you want:

```
res.send( "<h1>test complete</h1>" + data );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const filePath =  "/path/to/file" 
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
 fs.exists(filePath, function(exists){
      if (exists) {     
        res.writeHead(200, {
          "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
          "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=" + fileName
        });
        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
      } else {
        res.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end("ERROR File does not exist");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the content type, we can use `set` method as below.

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => 
{
    //trying to write some basic content to the page   
    fs.readFile('test.txt', (err, data) =>
    {        
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.send(data);       
    });
});
```

Ref:
http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set

Hope it helps